Connect to Serial port over Remote Connection
I have the below snippet of script I use regularly, which allows me to locate the device I have connected by using the port description, and from there do whatever I need to do.
ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
for p in ports:
    if 'Prolific USB-to' in p.description:
        time.sleep(1)
        find_com = re.findall(r'COM\d{0,9}',p.description)
        cmpt = (str(find_com))
        cmpt = cmpt.replace("['","").replace("']","")
        print('Device port identified as...',cmpt)
        device_Serial = open_ser(cmpt)
        print('port details here...',device_Serial)

I about to start working from home, connecting to my work PC using Remote Connection. I have the device I am testing with me at home and I also share my laptop's drives and ports over the connection to my work PC. Usually I expect the above code to cycle through all available Port connections, locating the specific one I have outlined, in this case 'Prolific USB-to' and from there cut down the 'port.description' information into a string I can then use to open a connection using 'open_ser()', which is defined earlier in the script.
'open_ser()' works as follows:
def open_ser(port):
    ser = serial.Serial(timeout=1, write_timeout=5)
    ser.baudrate =9600
    ser.port = port
    try:
        ser.open()
    except:
        # something went wrong
        print("Unable to open port", port)
        ser = None
    return ser

However, there is not Port description when connecting Tera Term over Remote Connection to the Device plugged into my laptop at home, only 'COM7' (as an example).
I am wondering how I might get the above snippet of code to detect a COM Port, when there is seemingly no information attributed to said port. Like I said, I am able to manually connect to the device at home using Tera Term over the remote connection, so I know it is theoretically possible.
I have tried the following also:
ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
for p in ports:
    if 'COM7' in p:
        time.sleep(1)
        find_com = re.findall(r'COM\d{0,9}',p)
        cmpt = (str(find_com))
        cmpt = cmpt.replace("['","").replace("']","")
        print('Device port identified as...',cmpt)
        device_Serial = open_ser(cmpt)
        print('port details here...',device_Serial)

However I have had no luck, and am clearly missing something. Any advice or a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

So the software you're running is at work and the COM port is at home?  I'm surprised Remote Connection even allows that, it's more than I would expect.

Yes that is correct, sorry if I didn't make that clear. Remote Connection allows for local Drives and posts to be shared across the connection.
